# Excel formula to look at a Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I wrote an excel formula to return(true and false) if three criteria's matched in the row.

***For ex) If the Row contained***
**Name , D, and 1 then it is true**

This is the formula created:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF('Target Book'!$A:$A," Person's Name"),
COUNTIF('Target Book'!$D:$D," D"),
COUNTIF('Target Book'!$F:$F,"1")),true,false)
```

However, it is looking at this to see if it is in the sheet not as a row as a whole. How can I modify this formula to look at the Row as a whole?

Comment: Do you know how to make it look at the whole row?

Comment: `I wrote an excel formula to return(true and false) if three criteria's matched in the row.` ... no you didn't ... your formula looks at whole columns, it does not care about rows

Comment: how does it look at columns? ... rows are accessed in a similar way ... start `record macro`, select a whole row, stop record, examine the resulting code

Comment: It looks at the columns as a whole A:A and etc. However,  I am trying to get it to look at the row to make sure all 3 criteria is there so that it can return the "True" value.... any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us a simple sample? According to your formula, it counts the Person's name in column A, counts " D" in column D and counts 1 in column F. Did you try row number? Such as COUNTIF('Target Book'!$1:$1," Person's Name").

Comment: @user1762802 `It looks at the columns as a whole A:A` that refers to column A ... think about how row 3 would be referred

Comment: This may do what you want maybe? `=IF(COUNTIFS('Target Book'!$A:$A," Person's Name",'Target Book'!$D:$D," D", 'Target Book'!$F:$F,"1")>0,true,false)` If not, it may be useful to show sample data and expected output